# jsoup tutorial throwing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, jsoup

I am following the Jsoup example to try to understand how it works and have copied and pasted all code as is, but I keep getting the error 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://news.ycombinator.com/ at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)
    at jsoup.examples.ListLinks.main(ListLinks.java:21)'.  IDE is NetBeans.  Where is the error?

```
package jsoup.examples;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
* Example program to list links from a URL.
*/
public class ListLinks {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "http://news.ycombinator.com/");
       String url = args[0];
       print("Fetching %s...", url);

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
    Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");

    print("\nMedia: (%d)", media.size());
    for (Element src : media) {
        if (src.tagName().equals("img"))
            print(" * %s: <%s> %sx%s (%s)",
                    src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"), src.attr("width"), src.attr("height"),
                    trim(src.attr("alt"), 20));
        else
            print(" * %s: <%s>", src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"));
    }

    print("\nImports: (%d)", imports.size());
    for (Element link : imports) {
        print(" * %s <%s> (%s)", link.tagName(),link.attr("abs:href"), link.attr("rel"));
    }

    print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
    for (Element link : links) {
        print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
    }
}

private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
    System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
}

private static String trim(String s, int width) {
    if (s.length() > width)
        return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
    else
        return s;
   }
}
```

Comment: could you post the complete exception ?

Comment: Did you pass the arguments while running? If you don't pass any parameter in the command prompt, it may cause errors.

Comment: Complete exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://news.ycombinator.com/
 at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)
 at jsoup.examples.ListLinks.main(ListLinks.java:21)

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but I do not understand what the args.length==1 does here. I'm very much in the beginning stages of Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response code being returned is 403, which means Forbidden.

Try setting the user agent before doing the get.  Something like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0").get();
```

Your code with the above change works for me.

Comment: @SheldonHughes Show me the stack trace that you get.

Comment: Try removing the Validate statement and see what you get.  Show me the complete stack trace.  Cut and paste everything.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://news.ycombinator.com/
 at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)
 at jsoup.examples.ListLinks.main(ListLinks.java:21)

Comment: The argument to the program should be: 'http : // news.ycombinator.com/' without the quotes and without the spaces.

Comment: Sorry. This is what you want, I think.   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at jsoup.examples.ListLinks.main(ListLinks.java:22)